# Is it possible to access a html control without an id

Tags: html

In my program, there are some links that will be created at run-time. They will contain the name of users which are selected from table. There is no id or name attribute set on these links.

How can I get the name of user corresponding to each link when I click on them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [can i get value from control which has no name or id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250306/can-i-get-value-from-control-which-has-no-name-or-id)

Comment: How do you want the data, where is the click happening? You are missing details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a variable that points to the calling element in just plain Javascript like this.

Javascript:

```
function myFunction(link)
{
    alert(link.innerText);
    return false;
}
```

Html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(this);">Bob</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jQuery like so:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var user_name = $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the HTML element using 3 different functions which are:

```
document.getElementById(id);
document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
document.getElementsByName(name);
```

use any of the following..

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++)
{
var value = links[i].value;
}
```

Comment: what about querySelector and querySelectorAll ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the nth-child selector? It selects an instance of a link based on the order it appears in the document, without using an ID or Class.

```
a:nth-child(2) {  

}
```

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/